# python variable assignment with ":"

Tags: python, variables, variable-assignment

[image]

```
def unexpected_exceptions(exctype, value, tb):
    exception = ''.join(traceback.format_exception(exctype, value, tb))
    _logger = logging.getLogger('unexpected_exceptions')
    _logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    f_handler: FileHandler = logging.FileHandler(os.path.join(BASE_PATH, 'log ' + CURRENT_VERSION + '.log'))

    f_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s:%(levelname)s:%(name)s:%(message)s'))
    _logger.addHandler(f_handler)
    _logger.exception(exception, exc_info=True)
    f_handler.close()
    _logger.removeHandler(f_handler)
    print(value)
```

sry i cound't find any article about this

what is this variable assignment ?

```
f_handler: FileHandler = logging.FileHandler(os.path.join(BASE_PATH, 'log ' + CURRENT_VERSION + '.log'))
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html

Comment: Thx a lot......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax is for type hint/annotation introduced in [python 3.5](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html)

This is used by tools to provide better hints, static checks etc. Note, this does not alter behaviour of python at all and is only a feature to help tools to provide additional support.

In the case you provided:

```
t:str=1
```

t is hinted to be a variable of type `str`. This shall allow your IDE to provide `str` methods on t when you press `.` !

This is the standard example from pydocs for type hints -

The function below takes and returns a string and is annotated as follows:

```
def greeting(name: str) -> str:
    return 'Hello ' + name
```

In the function greeting, the argument name is expected to be of type str and the return type str. Subtypes are accepted as arguments.